# how to mock a parametrized constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I've the following class. It has the code to connect to SAP in its constructor. There is an abstract method(the subclasses define the implementation) which I want to mock.

```
public abstract class BapiExecutor {
        ...
        public BapiExecutor(final SapConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
            throws java.lang.Exception {
        if (!validConnectorData()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Does not have valid data to connect to SAP");
        }
        initializeState(connectionInfo);
    }

    public abstract Object execute() throws Exception ;
        ....

}
```

The unit I want to test is :
I want to mock the call to `execute()` method.

```
private String invokeBapiToAddAssociation(Map associationMap,
            SapConnectionInfo connectionInfo) {
        EidCcBapiExecutor executor = null;
        String bapiExecutionResult = null;
        try {
            executor = new EidCcBapiExecutor(connectionInfo, associationMap);
            bapiExecutionResult = (String) executor.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new CcGenericException(
                    "Exception occurred while invoking the EID-CC Association BAPI executor!",
                    e);
        }
        return bapiExecutionResult;
    }
```

Any frameworks in Java that supports the mocking of parametrized constructors?

**i just want to avoid connecting to SAP in the constructor.**

Comment: You say something like this to it ... "With a body like that, its a good thing we can't see you in the raw".  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) with the [ClassImposteriser](http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html) can do that, as can most good mocking frameworks.

> The ClassImposteriser creates mock
>   instances without calling the
>   constructor of the mocked class. So
>   classes with constructors that have
>   arguments or call overideable methods
>   of the object can be safely mocked.

Comment: Looked into the code. Sounds cool. Never used JMock before. +1

Comment: It takes a bit of getting used to (the generics can get a bit hairy), but it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the mock class, subclassing the abstract BapiExecutor class, and implementing the behavior you want in execute() (or any other method). You don't need to revert to a framework here.

Could you please elaborate about what the blocking point is ?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the EidCcBapiExecutor  extends from BapiExecutor.

```
public class EidCcBapiExecutor extends BapiExecutor {
...
}
```

Than you could create the Mockup class for testing a specific method like:

```
public class EidCcBapiExecutorMockup extends EidCcBapiExecutor{

   public EidCcBapiExecutorMockup (final SapConnectionInfo connectionInfo){
     super(connectionInfo);
   }

   public Object execute() throws Exception {
      // You mockup code
   }
}
```

If you want to test the constructor you can create the class like:

```
public class EidCcBapiExecutorMockup extends EidCcBapiExecutor{

       public EidCcBapiExecutorMockup (){
         super(new SapConnectionInfo());
       }

    }
```

The object you place in the Constructor could be created in the setUp method of you JUnit test!